# Calling parent method inside sub classes super constructor

Tags: java

I'm self learning java and am working through some problems in my textbook on inheritance. The question is basically to make a superclass `Person` and to add two more classes `student` and `instructor` , where student has a major and instructor has a salary.

Anyways here is what I have so far

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String date;
    public Person(String name, String date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "The name of the person is :" + getName() + " And this person was born in " + getDate();
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student extends Person {

    private String major;

    public Student(String major)
    {
        super(super.getName(),super.getDate()); // ERROR
        this.major = major;
     }
}
```

**My Thought process**

Since every Student has a name and birth date, when I call the super constructor, I can just pass in the methods that return a `Person`'s name in my original super class. Obviously, as you can tell this isn't working The solution is just to do

```
public Student(String name, String birthDate, String major)
{
           super(name,birthDate);
           this.major = major;
}
```

I thought I would have saved making two extra variables in the constructor `Student`, by just calling the methods `.getName()` and `.getDate()`, i'm going through this chapter again, but am not really understanding where the issue lies.

**TLDR**
Whats wrong with the line

```
super(super.getName(),super.getDate());
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Let's assume that you could do `super(super.getName(),super.getDate());`, what values would actually get passed to the super constructor (in `Person`)?

Comment: Since every `Person` has a name and a birthdate, wouldn't those be passed as the base info for the student? from there , I can just have some methods that would manipulate the `major` of a `Student`

Comment: Do they have a name and a birthdate _yet_? Let's take your current example, what would `getName()` return?

Comment: Presumably, you want to call `new Student("Engineering")`. What name will it have?

Comment: The super constructor assigns the variables. The `getXXX()` methods return the variables. Gettting the variables before `super()` has set them doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see your point. In that case `Student` would not know what the `name` and `birthdate` are. However what if we said `Person person = new Person("Bob","Jan 1 2012")`, and then did `Student student = new Student('Engineering')`

Comment: Those are two unrelated objects you've just created.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. I'm going to toy around with a new idea you gave me and come back if I have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is like a blueprint of how an object would be created.

In your case you have got 2 classes, `Person` as the base class and then `Student` which inherits from `Person`.

When you tries to create an object from the `Student` class through the constructor method, the compiler will first go and build the `Person` object but note that at this stage, the base class `Person` is not built yet until you called `super()` constructor.

So when you say, I would like to use method from my "yet-to-built baseclass (Person)", since the compiler knows a head of time that this won't work because the parent object (which is accessible from the `super` keyword) is not there yet until `super()` **returns (finished running)**. Hence doing parent class.`getName()` method before the parent has been built is invalid.

Also like what many others say, even if you are able to use the `super.getName()` method, it won't have any values in it since it is not set with a default value.

Hope this helps, happy to discuss further.

Comment: It would neither 'die' nor 'fail'. It would however give possibly unexpected values for the variables in the superclass.

Comment: @EJP giving you rubbish value is incorrect because the compiler will not build in the first place. This is not C++. I have verified my facts with Java8. Try it.

Comment: I think I get now that `Student` Wont know what the `name` or `birthdate` is, but is that why my code gives an error? or is it the fact that as you say in the answer nothing is built yet until the `super()` is called??

Comment: @SamuelToh 'Giving you a rubbish value' is neither a death nor a failure. The program is working as written. The fact that this is not C++ is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok C++ or not is not important here as I am just quoting an example where if you use an uninitialized variable in C++ there is a chance you get rubbish values and core dump your application

Comment: @SamuelToh The fact that a C++ applicaton might core-dump is irrelevant, as this is not C++. You said so yourself. The code concerned isn't even legal C++ in the first place.

Comment: ... Just saying what would happen in C++. If I have made a mistake anywhere then I'm sorry. I'm just trying to help, not creating a fight.

Comment: Don't apologize: just fix your answer. That's the whole purpose of the comment system.

Comment: I commented too, if anyone cares to answer xD

Comment: @bill It gives an error because it doesn't make sense, as I stated under your question.

Comment: Added "Assuming the program compiles" to the died part. What do you think? Ok?

Comment: @bill The compiler is preventing you from building the application because it has a little bit of smartness in there to tell that the code won't work. Because you are referencing something that is yet to be built. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks thus we cannot call methods inside a constructor in general, correct?

Comment: @bill It is because you can't call methods on an object you haven't constructed yet.

Comment: @SamuelToh No. It is not correct to use the word 'die' or 'fail' in this answer in any way.

Comment: I thought `super()` just calls the parent constructor ( from what I remember in my book), what do you mean on an object you havent constructed yet?

Comment: @bill `super()` calls the parent constructor, which constructs the parent object. It isn't constructed until `super()` returns. The parameters to `super()` have to be evaluated before `super()` is called. *Ergo* it isn't constructed yet.

Comment: @bill Note the parent object only gets constructed after the `super()` gets executed finish.

Comment: @SamuelToh No. The parent object 'gets constructed' *by the `super()` call*. It is only *completely* constructed when `super()` has returned.

Comment: @SamuelToh NB re an earlier comment of yours, you have not verified either 'die' or 'fail' with any version of Java. It doesn't happen. Possibly you are just misusing words, in which case you need to correct your post.

Comment: @EJP Ok removed the word `die`.

Comment: so `super()` makes an object too? I thought `Person person = new Person()` is how we make new objects.

Comment: @bill I didn't say 'makes'. I said *constructs*, in the sense of calling the constructor. That initializes the `Person` part of the `Student` object.

Comment: @bill the constructor in `Person` builds the `Person` object but you are building the `Student` object here which inherits from `Person`. So building Student also means that you are building the base object as well

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you, this is hard to digest for a beginner, but I think I got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to super's methods in constructor. The super object is nothing (null) at the moment of running sub-class's constructor.